# Drag an element using JavaScript (Translating the position CSS3)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on a small task, where I have to drag `(translate)` an element anywhere in the document freely. I have done the basic work but confused about the current position of the mouse. Because when I start dragging the element, the mouse position is not on the spot where the `mousedown` occurs.

Simply, I want the position of the mouse to stay on where I clicked on the box.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dojrscq4/1/) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to calculate the width and height of the element in order to keep the cursor in its center, note that now it's working with any width and height values, here i have  added an animation just resizing width and height to  see that always we get the center of the element

```js
let target = document.querySelector(".drag");

function onDrag(e) {
  // we could make them global variables instead
  const {width, height} = window.getComputedStyle(target);
  target.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - +width.replace("px", "") / 2}px, ${e.clientY - +height.replace("px", "") / 2}px)`;
}

function onLetGo() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

function onGrab() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

target.addEventListener('mousedown', onGrab);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.drag{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  animation-name: resize;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes resize {
    0% {width: 100px}
    25% {height: 150px}
    50% {width: 150px}
    100% {height: 100px}
}
```

```html
<div class="drag"></div>
```

### Edited to answer the comment of the OP

> Thanks for the answer, it works fine. Is there any way, we can drag the div from any place where we click the div?

So now you want to drag the element from the clicked point and not from its center you can subtract `event.offsetX` from `event.clientX` to get the correct cursor position and the same for the y axis, and make sure there is no margin or padding for the containers, in this example I have removed the margin and padding from the HTML and BODY elements

```js
let target = document.querySelector(".drag"), x = 0, y = 0;

function onDrag(e) {
  // we use the coords of the mousedown event
  target.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - x}px, ${e.clientY - y}px)`;
}

function onLetGo() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

function onGrab(e) {
    // we store the point of click(coords)
    x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

target.addEventListener('mousedown', onGrab);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.drag{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="drag"></div>
```

Well because transition is affected by margin, padding and other flow control rules you can avoid using it and just use the `left` and `top` rules to properly position your element like this

```js
let target = document.querySelector(".drag"), x = 0, y = 0;

function onDrag(e) {
  // use the `left` and `top` rules to properly position your element, so 
  // you no more care about other flow affecting rules
  target.style.left = `${e.clientX - x}px`;
  target.style.top = `${e.clientY - y}px`;
}

function onLetGo() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

function onGrab(e) {
    x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onLetGo);
}

target.addEventListener('mousedown', onGrab);
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="drag"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works fine.

Is there any way, we can drag the div from any place where we click the div?