# Zooming in makes drag speed faster

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have made a dragging system with js and jquery, however when i zoom in, the image when being moved, moves faster then the cursor. also when i zoom out the image moves slower. I have tried to fix this but it just does weird movements.

```
$(function() {
  let count =  Date.now();
  let posX = 0
  let posY = 0
  document.querySelectorAll('.token').forEach(function(token) {
    function onDrag({movementX, movementY, buttons, target}) {

      if (buttons === 0) {$(token).css('z-index', 0); return;}
      let zoom = window.devicePixelRatio
      
      let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(token)
      let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
      let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
      token.style.left = `${leftVal + (movementX / zoom)}px`
      token.style.top = `${topVal + (movementY / zoom)}px`
      let tempcount = Date.now();
      if (tempcount > count + 30) {
        socket.emit('Token Updated', leftVal + (movementX / zoom), topVal + (movementY / zoom), token.classList[1], false)
        count = Date.now();
      }
      

     
    }
    token.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
      $('.token.' + event.target.classList[1]).css('z-index', 3000)
      token.classList.add("active")
      
      document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", onDrag)
    })
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener("mouseup", (event) =>  {
      document.querySelector("body").removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag)
      let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(token)
      let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
      let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
      $('.token.' + token.classList[1]).css('z-index', 2001)
      socket.emit('Token Updated', leftVal, topVal, token.classList[1], true)
      
    })
    
  })


})
```

Comment: since the question is hard to deal with at first glance I have a suggestion: you should include the html that will immediately make it a working demo (by adding a `.token` styled to be `position: absolute` and to have a fixed size. It may help people not skipping the question entirely. As per how to solve it, I think you should not use the `devicePixelRatio` to calibrate the movement but just apply the offset as given to a css `transform` [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610870/drag-an-element-using-javascript-translating-the-position-css3)